# Linking html and javascript to make clicker work?

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML and javascript interact perfectly when I'm using jsfiddle (which is what I made this in if that makes a difference). When I use google drive's hosting, the html displays correctly but no javascript interaction happens.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Click</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="clickerjs.js"></script>
    <button id="button">Click me</button>
    <button id="auto">Buy an autoclicker!</button>
    <button id="tupgrade">Time Upgrade!</button>
    <button id="cupgrade">Click Upgrade!</button>
    <div id="buytenup">Buy Ten</div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Clicks</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td id="clicks">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Click value</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td id="cvalue">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Autoclickers</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td id="autoAmount">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td id="time">1000ms</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Autoclicker cost</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td id="autocost">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Time upgrade cost</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td id="tupcost">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Click upgrade cost</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td id="cupcost">1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="console">Consoooooole</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's the JS:

```
var clicks = 0;
var autoCost = 1;
var autoClicks = 0;
var timer;
var tUpcost = 1;
var time = 1000;
var cUpcost = 1;
var clickValue = 1;


function update() {
    var e = document.getElementById("clicks");
    e.innerHTML = clicks;
    var e1 = document.getElementById("autoAmount");
    e1.innerHTML = autoClicks;
    var e2 = document.getElementById("autocost");
    e2.innerHTML = autoCost;
    var e3 = document.getElementById("tupcost");
    e3.innerHTML = tUpcost;
    var e4 = document.getElementById("cvalue");
    e4.innerHTML = clickValue;
    var e5 = document.getElementById("cupcost");
    e5.innerHTML = cUpcost;

}

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    clicks += clickValue;
    update();
};

document.getElementById("auto").onclick = function () {
    if (clicks < autoCost) {
        var x = document.getElementById("console");
        x.innerHTML = "Too expensive!";
    } else {
        clicks -= autoCost;
        autoClicks++;
        autoCost += 2;
        var z = document.getElementById("console");
        z.innerHTML = "Upgrade complete!";
    }
    update();
};

//Time
document.getElementById("tupgrade").onclick = function () {
    if (clicks < tUpcost) {
        var p = document.getGetElementById("console");
        p.innerHTML = "Too expensive!";
    } else {
        clicks -= tUpcost;
        time -= 2;
        tUpcost += 2;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            clicks += autoClicks;
            update();
        }, time);
        var l = document.getElementById("console");
        l.innerHTML = "Upgrade complete!";
        var o = document.getElementById("time");
        o.innerHTML = time + "ms";
    }
    update();
};

timer = setInterval(function () {
    clicks += autoClicks;
    update();
}, time);

document.getElementById("cupgrade").onclick = function () {
    if (clicks < cUpcost) {
        var h = document.getGetElementById("console");
        h.innerHTML = "Too expensive!";
    } else {
        clicks -= cUpcost;
        clickValue += 2;
        cUpcost += 2;
        var g = document.getElementById("console");
        g.innerHTML = "Upgrade complete!";
    }
    update();
};
```

Comment: make sure it is correct  `src="clickerjs.js"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you load your javascript before the DOM is created, you won't find any elements to bind the events.

**Solution 1:**

Put your javascript at the bottom in your body.

```
<body>
   // html markup

   // load the scripts here
</body>
```

**Solution 2:**

Wrap your code in an onload handler.

```
window.onload = function(){
    // Code comes here
};
```

Comment: But is there any reason in particular linking to the external file won't work?

Comment: Yes there is, I completed my answer, you can find it there.

Comment: JSFiddle runs it by default so always remember to wrap it in an onload handler.